# Do you need galaxy.yml when you start creating galaxy?

Tags: galaxy

First question: I found that there is no galaxy.yml in the config directory of the running version of docker galaxy, only galaxy.yml.sample file and galaxy.yml.interactivatetools file, so do I need to create it, or do I need to create a new one using the cat command? galaxy.yml file?
The second question is about these initial notes, where can I go deeper?

Comment: What have you already tried? Does Galaxy work for you if you run it without a .yml file? Have you looked at the galaxy documentation on the Galaxy website?